# Node.js Buffers vs Typed Array - performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, websocket

To send binary messages with [WebSocket](https://github.com/websockets/ws), I can use either [Node.js Buffers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_buffers.htm) or [Typed Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays).

Is there a significantly difference in term of **performance** between them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As they both utilise raw memory under the hood, I doubt you will find any noticeable performance differences **in general**. That being said, performance is usually more about *how you use* these structures.

As you should never prematurely optimise, it is unlikely that a choice between two with regards to performance is going to make any difference to your application. I would suggest choosing the type whose api best suits your needs, making your code more readable, and easier to debug. `TypedArrays` would allow you to have consistent code at both client and server, while `Buffer`s don't need to be initialised to zero. Each would have other pros and cons.

If performance did eventually become an issue, these types could also easily be swapped out, and separately profiled.